# Problema con float y str en python

Tags: python

estoy teniendo un error en mi codigo, no se bien que es lo que me esta indicando el error o que puede signifar, ya intente modificar los valor por str por float, etc y sigue sin funcionar, no comprendo cual es el valor que tengo que modificar para que se pueda ejecutar la resta que si o si tengo que generar para que el programa funcione.

El tema es que es un trabajo para la facultad y en la consigna me veo limitado a utilizar solo lo que se ve en el codigo por si a alguien le surge la duda de por que no utilizo codigo menos rebuscado.

El error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in <module>
    prenda_gratis1 = (precio_total) - (prenda_precio1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

---

```
print("Seleccione la prenda de su agrado: ")
print("remeras $150, ", "camisas $300, ", "pantalones $400, ", "faldas $ 200, ", "vestidos $300, ", "abrigos $500, ", "calzado $400.")
print("\n")
print("Super Puntos:\n"
  "remeras 100P, ", "camisas 200P, ", "pantalones 250P, ", "faldas 150P, ", "vestidos 200P, ", "abrigos 450P, ","calzado 250P" )
print("\n")

#Asignacion de prendas y precios.
prenda1 = input(str("Ingrese la prenda n° 1: "))
precio1= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

prenda2 = input(str("Ingrese la prenda n° 2: "))
precio2= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

prenda3 = input(str("Ingrese la prenda n° 3: "))
precio3= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

prenda_precio1 = (prenda1) + str(precio1)
prenda_precio2 = (prenda2) + str(precio2)
prenda_precio3 = (prenda3) + str(precio2)


#Sumatoria de prendas y sus respectivos precios.
precio_total = precio1 + precio2 + precio3
print("Total sin promo: " + "$" + str(precio_total))

#Tipo de pago.
pago_unico = input("Ingrese la forma de pago: ")
#Pago contado
if (pago_unico == "contado") or (pago_unico == "Contado"):
  total_descuento = precio_total - ((precio_total * 10) / 100)
  print("Total descuento: " + "$" + str(total_descuento))
  ahorro_total = ((precio_total * 10) / 100)
  print("Ahorro total: " + "$" + str(ahorro_total))

#Pago con tarjeta
elif (pago_unico == "tarjeta") or (pago_unico == "Tarjeta"):
  cantidad_cuotas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de cuotas: "))
  if cantidad_cuotas <= 3:
    pago_tarjeta = precio_total + ((precio_total * 2) / 100)
    print("Recargo del 2% hasta 3 cuotas: " + "$" + str(pago_tarjeta))
  elif int(cantidad_cuotas >= 4) and (cantidad_cuotas < 24):
    pago_tarjeta = precio_total + ((precio_total * 5) / 100)
    print("Recargo del 5% hasta 24 cuotas: " + "$" + str(pago_tarjeta))
  else:
    print("Solo aceptamos hasta 24 cuotas sin interes.\nSaludos")
else:
  print("Forma de pago incorrecta!")

#Promociones------
#Promo 3x2
"""n1 > n2, n1 > n3
   n2 > n1, n2 > n3
   n3 > n1, n3 > n2"""

if (prenda1 == prenda2 == prenda3) or (prenda3 == prenda2 == prenda3):
    if (precio1 == precio2) or (precio1 == precio3):
      print("Dos prendas con el mismo precio.\nNo participa de la PROMO 3X2.")
    elif (precio2 == precio1) or (precio2 == precio3):
      print("Dos prendas con el mismo precio.\nNo participa de la PROMO 3X2.")
    elif (precio3 == precio1) or (precio3 == 2):
      print("Dos prendas con el mismo precio.\nNo participa de la PROMO 3X2.")
    elif (precio1 < precio2) and (precio1 < precio3):
      print("La prenda numero uno es gratis, PROMO 3X2: " + str(prenda_precio1))
      prenda_gratis1 = (precio_total) - (prenda_precio1)
      print("Total con PROMO 3X2: " + str(prenda_gratis1))
    elif (precio2 < precio3) and (precio2 < precio1):
      print("La prenda numero dos es gratis, PROMO 3X2: " + str(prenda_precio2))
      prenda_gratis2 = precio_total - (prenda_precio2)
      print("Total con PROMO 3X2: " + str(prenda_gratis2))
    elif (precio3 < precio2) and (precio3 < precio1):
      print("La prenda numero tres es gratis, PROMO 3X2: " + str(prenda_precio3))
      prenda_gratis3 = precio_total - (prenda_precio3)
      print("Total con PROMO 3X2: " + str(prenda_gratis3))
    else:
      print("Dos prendas o mas con el mismo precio.")
else:
    print("Valores erroneos!")
```

Answer (score 0):

En la línea 65 estás tratando `prenda_precio1` como un número para restarlo de otro pero es un str (la concatenación de la prenda y su precio). Parece que estás usando una variable que no es la correcta.